# Cassandra read write latency for large partition

Tags: database, cassandra, latency

For a large cassandra partition read latencies are usally huge. 
But does write latency get impacted in this case? Since cassandra is columnar database and holds immutable data, shouldn't the write (which appends data at the end of the row) take less time?

Comment: Do you have a write-only system? The problem lies in that read/write clashes each other... And have you considered compactions in this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

In all the experiments I have conducted with Cassandra, I have noticed that write throughput is not affected by data size while read performance takes a big hit if your SSTables are too big, concurrent_reads threads are low ( check using `nodetool tpstats` if `ReadStage` is going into pending state) and increase them in `cassandra.yaml` file. Using `LeveledCompaction` seems to help as data for same key remains in same SSTable. Make sure your data is distributed evenly across all nodes. Cassandra optimization is tricky and you may have to implement "hacks" to obtain desired performance in minimum possible hardware.